# Fill nan values in test data with mean values form train data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply, fillna

I am trying to fill nan values from test data with mean value from train data on multiple columns based or grouped by a column. Here is part of the test data:

[image]

```
    date_block_num  shop_id     item_id     item_category_id    target  item_price  avg_item_price  sum_item_cnt_day    avg_item_cnt_day    shop_avg_item_price     ...     avg_item_cnt_day_lag_12     shop_avg_item_price_lag_12  shop_sum_item_cnt_day_lag_12    shop_avg_item_cnt_day_lag_12    category_avg_item_price_lag_12  category_sum_item_cnt_day_lag_12    category_avg_item_cnt_day_lag_12    shop_avg_item_price_per_category_lag_12     shop_sum_item_cnt_per_category_lag_12   shop_avg_item_cnt_per_category_lag_12
0   26.5    5   5037    19.0    0.928571    1788.897788     1934.764286     90.714286   1.937141    868.822366  ...     0.383736    619.341077  181.571429  0.029328    716.813821  779.214286  0.084066    716.052585  10.285714   0.056515
1   NaN     5   5320    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   30.0    5   5233    19.0    1.428571    854.861715  842.778086  72.428571   1.685456    914.767445  ...     0.000000    597.460870  0.000000    0.000000    591.507516  0.000000    0.000000    591.790514  0.000000    0.000000
3   32.0    5   5232    23.0    0.333333    728.018465  790.297277  47.000000   1.100087    965.966832  ...     0.000000    597.460870  0.000000    0.000000    591.507516  0.000000    0.000000    591.790514  0.000000    0.000000
4   NaN     5   5268    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN

5 rows × 102 columns
```

So I want replace nans with the mean value of a column based on item_id.

**first** I know that I can get the mean of the columns of the train data grouped by item_id as follows:

```
mt = train.groupby('item_id').apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

**Then** I see that I try to use fillna for each column in test set as follows:

```
for col in test.columns:

    test[col] = test.groupby('item_id')[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna...)
```

I cannot get how to replace with mean values from the train and not test. How to do it? And is this the best way or there is a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the data you included as picture by doing `print(df.head())` and pasting the output in your question? We probably dont need all columns to answer the question, so I would make a sub selection of collumns as well by: `df[[date_bock_num, shop_id..]]`

Comment: Well I tried but copy paste is not displaying the output correctly. I did it but it is not displayed correctly.

Comment: the selection does not matter. it is how the nans are filled with values form other set. Any example which shows how this works is fine.

Comment: Does your `train` and `test` dataframes have the same shape? The same amount of columns and rows?

Comment: only same amount of columns after adding extra features form train

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your `train` and `test` dataframe have the same shape (# rows, # cols)**

We can use [`pandas.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)
for this, but not in combination with the aggregation that happens in `groupby` since `combine_first` replaces `NaN` with the values on the same position in the other dataframe.

Thats why we need to use [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) for this, since it keeps the `shape` of our dataframe the same:

```
# make two example dataframes
train = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[5037, 5320, 5037, 5320],
                      'num1': [10, 8, 9, 5],
                      'num2': [3, 5, 1, 9]})

test = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[5037, 5320, 5037, 5320],
                     'num1': [6, np.NaN, 3, 7],
                     'num2': [np.NaN, 4, np.NaN, 9]})

print(train, '\n')
print(test)

   item_id  num1  num2
0     5037    10     3
1     5320     8     5
2     5037     9     1
3     5320     5     9 

   item_id  num1  num2
0     5037   6.0   NaN
1     5320   NaN   4.0
2     5037   3.0   NaN
3     5320   7.0   9.0
```

We apply `groupby.transform` and `combine_first`

```
train_means = train.groupby('item_id').transform('mean')
test.combine_first(train_means)

   item_id  num1  num2
0     5037   6.0   2.0
1     5320   6.5   4.0
2     5037   3.0   2.0
3     5320   7.0   9.0
```

**If your `train` and `test` dataframe DO NOT have the same shape (# rows, # cols)**,
it gets a bit more complex.

We can do the following:

1. We can get the mean of each `item_id` and the valeus with [`pandas.groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)
2. After that we [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get the means of each corresponding `item_id` and mean of `train` dataframe to our `test` dataframe.
3. Then we make a dict of our column names and we conditionally fill our `NaN` with the values of the same column which came from our `train` dataset where `groupby` was applied on. And we use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this.

```
train_grp = train.groupby('item_id').mean().reset_index()

print(train_grp)
   item_id  num1  num2
0     5037   9.5   2.0
1     5320   6.5   7.0
```

Apply merge

```
test_merged = test.merge(train_grp, on='item_id', suffixes=['_test', '_train'])

print(test_merged)
   item_id  num1_test  num2_test  num1_train  num2_train
0     5037        6.0        NaN         9.5         2.0
1     5037        3.0        NaN         9.5         2.0
2     5320        NaN        4.0         6.5         7.0
3     5320        7.0        9.0         6.5         7.0
```

Create dictionary of corresponding columns

```
test_cols = [col for col in test_merged.columns if 'test' in col]
train_cols = [col for col in test_merged.columns if 'train' in col]
dict_cols =dict(zip(test_cols, train_cols))

print(dict_cols)
{'num1_test': 'num1_train', 'num2_test': 'num2_train'}
```

Conditionally replace the `Nan`

```
for test, train in dict_cols.items():
    test_merged[test] = np.where(test_merged[test].isnull(), 
                                 test_merged[train], 
                                 test_merged[test])

# Clean up dataframe
test_merged.drop(train_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
test_merged.columns = test_merged.columns.str.replace('_test', '')

print(test_merged)
   item_id  num1  num2
0     5037   6.0   2.0
1     5037   3.0   2.0
2     5320   6.5   4.0
3     5320   7.0   9.0
```

**Explanation**
`np.where` works as follows: `np.where(condition, value if true, value if false)`